# How to return a formatted array of unique objects by value with underscore?

Tags: underscore.js

Input:

```
var animals = [
    {category: "mammal", name: "dog", categoryID: "MAM"},
    {category: "fish", name: "pickerel", categoryID: "FIS"},
    {category: "mammal", name: "cat", categoryID: "MAM"},
    {category: "mammal", name: "monkey", categoryID: "MAM"},
    {category: "bird", name: "budgie", categoryID: "BIRD"}
];
```

Desired output:

```
var categories = [
 {name: "mammal", catId: "MAM"},
 {name: "bird", catId: "BIR"},
 {name: "fish", catId: "FIS"}
];
```

Is there a nice way to do it with underscore?

The closest I got was this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L69CF/):

```
var categories = _.groupBy(animals, function(animal) {
                    return animal.category;
                });
```

With this output:

```
Object {mammal: Array[3], fish: Array[1], bird: Array[1]}
```

But is there a way to return the desired output above in a nice way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`reduce`](http://underscorejs.org/#reduce) instead of [`groupBy`](http://underscorejs.org/#groupBy) to collect your names and IDs in a convenient format:

```
var collect_categories = function(o, e) {
    o[e.categoryID] = e.category;
    return o;
};
var o = _(animals).reduce(collect_categories, { })
```

and then a [`map`](http://underscorejs.org/#map) to unpack that object into an array of objects:

```
var unpack = function(name, id) {
    return { name: name, catID: id };
};
var a = _(o).map(unpack);
```

The helper functions make more sense when you combine those with [`chain`](http://underscorejs.org/#chain):

```
var categories = _(animals).chain()
                           .reduce(collect_categories, { })
                           .map(unpack)
                           .value();
```

I find that naming the functions makes the code less cluttered than anonymous functions and the names help to signal the code's intent.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/aS47C/